# URL structure for laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel (first project ) but not new to PHP. I am creating a housing listing website with laravel 5.2. I need to create a location based listing such as  **/listing/country/province/city/UNIQUEIDENTIFIED**

I would like to setup the views  as follows:

```
/listing/{country}/{province}/{city}/UNIQUEIDENTIFIED
```

and the Controller should return all houses based on the specified variables.

**If NO CITY is specified, I return listings on provincial level.**

How do we set up dynamic views properly in a SEO friendly URL structure?

Comment: You will need to get the specified variables values and use conditional logic to fetch data as per your need.

Comment: I was  hoping to avoid that. I was hoping that  /canada/british-columbia/vancouver/ would pull all houses in Vancouver, BC, Canada. I know I can parse the URL and map the resulting ARRAY to specific variables though, jkust that it's long :) Thanks for the help

Comment: have you tried optional parameters in your route: /listing/{country}/{province?}/{city?}/ Would probably have to modify your queries though.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I haven't tried that yet. I am trying something that may be so much simpler: Parsing the actual URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much easier way to parse the URL inside the Controller, and then return the outcome to the view as follows:

```
public function getListing2(Request $request){

    $maurl = $request->path();
    $url_parts = parse_url($maurl);
    $path_parts = explode('/', trim($url_parts['path'], '/'));
    $var1 = $path_parts[0];
    $var2 = $path_parts[1];
    $var3 = $path_parts[2];




//DO my code 

//Create the HTML object 


    return HTML OBJECT . . . . . . ; // :)

  }
```